# groovy class method not returning expected result

Tags: groovy

```
class Items{
    List list
    
    Items(List list){
        list = list
    }
    
    def render(){
        return ("these are my items: ${list.collect{new Item(it).render()}.join(' ')}")
    }
}

class Item{
    List item
    
    Item(String item){
        item = item
    }
    
    def render(){
        return ("* ${item}")
    }
}

new Items(['foo', 'bar']).render()
```

I expect result to return `'these are my items: * foo * bar'` but instead it returns `'these are my items:'`. The equivalent syntax works in JS.

This appears to be an async issue but am unsure how to fix. I have done a bit of searching and found an ExecutorService API but am unsure how to incorporate..

**Question**

Can someone please edit this groovy snip-it so that the return yields `'these are my items: * foo * bar'`? I would like to maintain multi-class JS react-like structure if possible.

Comment: Your `Item.item` is a `List` and not a `String`. Your constructurs need to be `this.x = x`.

Comment: Async issue? I don't understand what you mean by that. Your constructors are missing `this.xxx` (both of them); you're assigning the parameter to itself. `Item`'s item should be a string according to the rest of your code.

Comment: Ha using "this" did the trick although I did have a typo as well.

Comment: @BGS Not if your parameter is named the same thing as the instance variable--how would it know what you're referring to? https://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_positional_parameters

Comment: Sorry clearly things I still do not know ha.. I feel like I have gotten away with not using "this" for instantiated class in groovy before. So you always have to "this" with instantiated class to refer to the class fields?

Comment: @DaveNewton that makes sense. I think that has tripped me up a lot actually. I have seen in some code snippits to use CAPs for class fields. A good practice it seems if you are not going to use "this".

Comment: Those are instance fields, not class fields. IMO groovy should still follow Java naming standards to avoid confusion--capital letters are generally reserved for static constants.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Items{
    List list
    
    Items(List list){
        this.list = list
    }
    
    def render(){
        return ("these are my items: ${list.collect{new Item(it).render()}.join(' ')}")
    }
}

class Item{
    String item
    
    Item(String item){
        this.item = item
    }
    
    def render(){
        return ("* ${item}")
    }
}

new Items(['foo', 'bar']).render()
```

Comment: If you want to get rid of the c'tors, you could use `groovy.transform.TupleConstructor` annotations on both classes.

Answer (score 1):

Including this to be incrementally more Groovy-like.

Groovy has implicit returns and the extra parents aren't necessary.

Personally I'm not a fan of large string interpolations like this either; I'd pull it out into an intermediate variable.

```
class Items {
  List list
    
  def render() {
    "these are my items: ${list.collect { new Item(item: it).render() }.join(' ')}"
  }
}

class Item {
  String item
    
  def render() {
    "* ${item}"
  }
}

println(new Items(list: ['foo', 'bar']).render())
```

Comment: I like it. Thanks for the help.